# Using Cython to create parallel threads without prange

Tags: python, recursion, parallel-processing, cython

I have a recursive function that does something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np

from copy import copy

shared_data = np.random.randn(6, 5, 3)

def grow(current_data, level):

    grown_data = []
    if level <  shared_data.shape[0] - 1:
        nlevel = level + 1
        valid = ((shared_data[nlevel] - current_data[-1])**2).sum(axis=-1) < 1
        for new_data in shared_data[nlevel, valid]:
            continue_data = copy(current_data)
            continue_data.append(new_data)
            grown_data.extend(grow(continue_data, level+1))

    else:
        grown_data.append(current_data)

    return grown_data

begin_data = np.random.randn(3)

print(grow([begin_data], 0))
```

I am wondering if there is some way to start a new parallel thread in cython to do the current processing on each entry for the grow function in order to speed this type of recursion up.  While the above sample code runs relatively fast, the actual code is slower (a) because it does more than the simple distance calculation included above and (b) because the data it is operating on is more like the size (3000, 10, 3), which even for this simple example is prohibitively slow, at least on my machine.

One thought that I had was to use a list/queue to add recursive jobs to instead of calling them directly, then, on each return from grow, using a prange loop to process the jobs in the list/queue in parallel, but I'm afraid this will result in the recreation of threads all the time and decrease the efficiency.

Comment: I would like to clarify that memory is not the issue here, processing speed is.  At worst case the code as is only uses up about 10% of the memory for the system.

Comment: You could use the standard Python `threading` module. If you can wrap the slow bits in a `with nogil:` block in Cython then this should work fine.

Comment: So you are saying use the standard python threading module to create a new thread for each call to grow and then release the gil in grow, which should enable to threads to operate in parallel?

Comment: Yes - that would work. Or use something like the [standard queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to manage it. My main point is that if you release the GIL in Cython then it works fine with the normal Python threading tools.

Comment: @DavidW  Your comment works.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.